# ClientPeoplePicker is undefined

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering

I'm trying to get ClientPeoplePicker control with following code.

```
    function setCPP(userAccountName, controlName) {
    var peoplePickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + controlName + "']");
    var peoplePickerEditor = peoplePickerDiv.find("[title='" + controlName + "']");
    var spPeoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerDiv[0].id];
    peoplePickerEditor.val(userAccountName);
    spPeoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
}
```

I can get `peoplePickerEditor` and `peoplePickerDiv[0].id` without problem, but `spPeoplePicker` is `undefined`.
What did I miss?

Comment: See here, included all required javascript references? According to that article, it is meant for SharePoint hosted apps so it seems. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Resolved issue by adding timeout. Before that the function works in IE11, with timeout added also works in IE10.

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            setCPP(userAccountName, controlName);
        }, 2000);
    }, 'clientpeoplepicker.js');
```